# Spring and SOA application

Tags: java, spring, rest, soa, restful-authentication

I'm new to WEB SOA applications and i have several questions about how to implements this architecture.

I would like to make a SOA based application involving multiple services using spring restfull api.
I'm aware of how to build each service itself.

i've already made a maven based project exposing a restful service using spring boot and secured it using spring security... my problem is to implement several services:

1. I don't know if i have to make a project for each one or there's a better solution... i want them to communicate through XML/Json so they won't be in same project in my point of view.
2. All secured by same service which makes use of spring security, i don't know how to link between the security service and the other ones. i don't want to write same security config classes on each project and then the user would be asked for sign in each time he accesses one of the services.
3. Share some resources which are used by all most services such as domain model classes, since i don't want to copy paste them (make duplicates), if i would change anything i would have to make changes in all services ... horrible :/

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

> 1- Secure them all (the entire application) using one service which
>   make use of spring security and which will be asked for whenever a
>   client access one of the services.

This link will help you : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3s2lSD50-JI

> 2- Share some resources which are used by all most services such as
>   domain model classes.

Here it is about how to organize your project in your IDE or in your architecture. Using packages, shared libraries, shared projects or [maven modules](https://books.sonatype.com/mvnex-book/reference/multimodule.html) can help you.

> 3- Deploy all services inside one " application container ".

Your IDE or Maven should be able to help you deploy you application in a container. In the case of Spring Boot, there is an embedded Tomcat server that can run your application. Or if you have your Tomcat stand alone installation, you can deploy it by your self.

Reading you post, I guess your are new in Spring Boot development. The learning path I can suggest is the following (in my point of view) :

1. [N-Tier](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multitier_architecture) Pattern for application architecture, and the purpose of the layers
2. The architecture of the [Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RsQ1tFLwldY) and [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol
3. [SOA](https://www.javatpoint.com/service-oriented-architecture) and [REST](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/whatisrest.html) Services
4. [Maven](https://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html) to build and compile your projects
5. [Spring Boot](http://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/), in mostly moderns architectures used to implement Backends my exposing REST Services

You can find by Googling tones of well explained documentations and blogs concerning those subjects.

Comment: Maybe I mis explained my problem, because i'm already familliar with all that and i've already made a maven based project exposing a restful service using 
spring boot and secured it using spring security... my problem is to implement several services:

1- I don't know if i have to make a project for each one or there's a better solution... i want them to communicate through XML/Json 
so they won't be in same project in my point of view.
2- All secured by same service which makes use of spring security, i don't know how to link between the security service and the other ones.

Comment: 3- I can't use packages since each service will be in a different project.. maven modules aren't possible also since each project for each service 
won't be a **pom** project.
4- I don't see any way to start all services under same " container ", except spring integration which I have not yet completely grasped. Thanks for answer and excuse my ignorance

Comment: I think you should edit your post with those details you just added. You can develop differents services in different project and they will communicate via REST services like Server to server communication. Then you will have differents jar or differents war files, you can deploy all on the same server.

Comment: Thanks for the answer about deployement, now how to secure all those services using only 1 service which makes use of Spring security ? i don't want to write same security config classes on each project and then the user would be asked for sign in each time he accesses one of the services. And how to share domain model classes over all projects since i don't want to copy paste them (make duplicates), if i would change anything i would have to make changes in all services ... horrible :/

Comment: What I can suggest is to write a Controller to manage your security and make this Controller as your entry to all the services in your project. If you want to share domain model classes, you have to share your domain a a library with other project (Maven Module).

Comment: Thanks i'll use the domain model as a dependency then... just a last question... if i put the same security controller as an entry for each service, is the user gonna be asked for authentification each time he accesses a different services ? because it would be ugly xD .... try to put your comments into the response so that i check the thread as solved x)

Comment: When you are connected, your role is set and you have access to the pages of your application. Unless you set a timeout to your session or you logout, your session should be still active to allow you to access your services.

Comment: What do you mean with SOA and REST Services? Do you mean SOAP? SOA is an architecture pattern and not a service implementation. SOA services may be technically implemented with SOAP, REST, CORBA etcetera.